# Is there a need to have XSS filters when I'm saving data as XML?

Tags: xss, encoding, xml

My web-app takes some configs from the user and saves into an XML file (it was not done to stop XSS). The input is XML encoded so that the `"`,`&` ... and such characters don't break the XML structure.

So is there a need to have another layer of XSS filter or will this way of saving the data automatically stops XSS attacks.

I'm aware of the fact that this attack depends on lots and lots of other factors such as rendering the webpage but lets confine the discussion to the following code snippet, however since the way I'm going to print the data very from time to time you are free to modify 
`echo "<h1> Hello ".$name."</h1>"` to show me any wrong ways of printing data.

```
$data = $_POST['malicious_user_supplied_data'];
$xml_encoded_data = xml_encode($data);
write_to_xml_as($xml_encoded_data,"config.xml");

------ config.xml --------
<user>
   <name>&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;BigBang&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;</name>
</user>
--------------------------    

$name = get_name("config.xml") // would return &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;BigBang&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;

echo "<h1> Hello ".$name."</h1>" // which on the browser would print &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;BigBang&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

Please show me some working examples where the above XML filter can be broken, if there are any.

Comment: Assuming `get_name` returns the XML decoded version of `name`, you will need to HTML encode it for output in your page (`echo` statement).

Comment: @SilverlightFox I've made some edits, the `get_name` does not decode anything

Comment: Keep it simple.... make `get_name` XML decode because you expect that to return a name in plain text. Then HTML encode when output to HTML (e.g. inline on your `echo` call).

Comment: With what headers is the HTML served?  If you don't have any `<meta charset="...">` or equivalent header, then encoding-level attacks might be possible.

Comment: Writing and reading from a file is subject to race conditions.  Does the kind of file system you're on make it impossible for `get_name` see the beginning of one write from `write_to_xml_as` and the end of another?

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks for your comment, can you please share some examples/links about the encoding-level attacks that could be possible here ? I don't have the `<mea charset="..."` header in the app

Comment: @vikkyhacks, [UTF-7 attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#UTF-7_encoding) were the canonical example of encoding level attacks.  Modern browsers are immune, but there might be other ways to cause the browser to see a `'<'` character without the XML containing a `'<`` byte.  For example, if your write treats the input as ASCII, and your XML parser expects UTF-8 and treats [overly-long UTF-8 sequences](https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/80.html) as text nodes and normalizes the output.

Comment: have you thought of DOM based XSS?
I havent read you code to be honest, but I have seen cases where XSS encoded sites decodes the piece of input to use it and while using the code, XSS occurs in the DOM.

I wasnt even sure if I should have stated this as DOM based or stored xss..

Anyhow, here is a weird case for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use JSON instead of XML. It is easier to understand how the parser works and so the security risks are much lower. For example you have to turn off loading external entities with `libxml_disable_entity_loader(true)` if you don't want an XXE attack, and so on.

The other part of the question is the generation of HTML, SVG etc. in the browser. For example with `innerHTML = "..."` it is easy to inject javascript. With `data` tags it is possible to inject javascript into firefox, so filtering only `script` tags is not enough... You have to use always DOM functions like `createTextNode()` instead of `innerHTML`. You don't need a server side storage to inject javascript. Displaying cookie or query parameters using javascript is more than enough. On server side you have to use DOM functions either, I am uncertain how secure they really are, but they are much better than concatenating strings... Ofc. you have to filter against HTML elements, etc... But if you need a rich text editor then you have a big problem...

I think one layer of security is never enough, and in this case it is certainly not enough. This is because HTML parsers are very complex piece of technology, and most developer (including me) only understands the basics of them. What you really need in this case are [some security headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers), like `Content-Security-Policy`. So the injected script won't be able to communicate with the attacker domain. (Ofc. this does not work in old browsers like ie6.)

Comment: +1 for XXE. That's dangerously underestimated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, if above code is fully secured, as you didn't provide us the definition of `xml_encode` function. Basing on your input/output samples, it looks, that `xml_encode` is similar to `htmlspecialchars` which could be used to sanitize your XML data too.

If I were you, I'd decide to use `htmlspecialchars` with correct flags (`ENT_QUOTES`) or libraries for building XML docs (e.g. `DOMDocument::createTextNode` will do encoding for you).

As there is no definition of `xml_encode` function, let's play with black-box guessing, what could go wrong here.

- Incorrect encoding:
  You need to make sure that webapplication sets the correct charset (e.g. UTF-8). Otherwise, your webapp could be vulnerable to XSS UTF-7 attacks. This problem concerns only old browsers.
- UTF-8 characters:
  Does `xml_encode` encode UTF-8 characters? How they are displayed after encoding process?
- CDATA section:
  This one could be the tricky one, if your `xml_encode` ignores CDATA sections. These sections inform the parser, that there is no markup in the characters inside CDATA. You have to make sure, that `< > " &` are also encoded inside CDATA.
- Single apostrophe:
  Is single apostrophe also encoded? If no, then you have to take care, while displaying data from XML.
  `<input type='text' value='<?php echo get_name("config.xml"); ?>' />`.
  Above example shows vulnerable code, as an attacker, could inject `aa' autofocus='on' onfocus='alert(1)` as his payload.
- Tag names: Are you planning to allow the user, to control tag-names too? If yes, then you have to be aware, that there is a chance to perform XSS directly from .xml file. Take a look [here](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?2,15296).